# why does the regex in my rewrite condition seem to not catch?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have URLs like the following:

```
mysite.com/eng?sentence=dog
```

and I want to rewrite them as

```
mysite.com/eng/dog
```

so I want to replace `?sentence=` with a "/"

I have tried all of the following:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ sentence= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ \?sentence= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ \?sentence=([^/?&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/+\?sentence=([^/?&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,NE]
```

then I tried accessing the URL:

```
mysite.com/eng?sentence=cat
```

but it stays as it is. I assume my regex logic is not correct and the rewrite cond is never satisfied. I always have trouble with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(eng)\?sentence=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/? [L,R]
```

This will redirect `http://mysite.com/eng?sentence=dog` into `http://mysite.com/eng/dog/`

Comment: I do not want it to redirect. I only want a rewrite.

Comment: Most likely mod_rewrite isn't enabled for you. Can you check your Apache error.log?

Comment: Does the last edit work? Also post your latest and complete .htaccess in your question so that I can debug and suggest.